# Can we pass multiple options for UIView's transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion: method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am trying to pass multiple options for `UIView`'s `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` method.

More specifically, I want both the `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp` and `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` options, as my UI gets unresponsive during the animation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just use the `|` operator to perform a bitwise OR of them, combining them - for example:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
       duration:0.2
       options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
       animations:^{ [fromView removeFromSuperview]; [containerView addSubview:toView]; }
       completion:NULL];
```

Comment: not to be that guy, but that's actually bitwise OR, not logical OR

Comment: You're not being 'that' guy at all - I'm completely wrong, you're right, thanks for pointing it out, that was a silly mistake to make! Edited accordingly, cheers.